# How to position List items horizontally in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom control which I am initializing manually [without the help of the designer]:

```
// Form1.cs
private byte totalControls;
private List<MyControl> controls;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    totalControls = 22;
    controls = new List<MyControl>(totalControls);
    for (byte i = 0; i < totalControls; i++)
    {
        controls.Add(new MyControl(i));
        panel1.Controls.Add(controls[i]);

        // My Problem:
        controls[i].Location = new Point(3 + (32 * i), 3);
        if ((i % 10 == 0) && (i != 0))
        {
            controls[i].Location = new Point(3 + (32 * i), 3 + (32 * i));
        }

        controls[i].Name = "myControl" + i.ToString();
        controls[i].Size = new Size(32, 32);
        controls[i].TabIndex = i;
        controls[i].Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

So as you see from the `Location` I set for each control, I am trying to position each `32x32` sized control in horizontal order next to each other. But I also want to increment `Location.Y` by `Size.Y` every 10 iterations - this would make the controls start another row. I would also need to reset `Location.X` somehow.

I need to have every 10 controls appear 32 pixels below the previous 10. Using the modulus operator does that only to the 10th control and doesn't even set its position right...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While this is totally possible, I just wanted to comment on the possibility that you might find the FlowLayoutPanel a nice container for handling these types of situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea with modulo is quite ok, here's a working version

```
int verticalOffset = 32;
var horizontalOffset = 32;
var numberOfControlsPerRow = 10;
controls[i].Location = new Point(
    3 + horizontalOffset*(i%numberOfControlsPerRow),
    3 + verticalOffset*(i/numberOfControlsPerRow)
);
// remove the if-statement
```

As you can see, I use `%` for the x coordinate. In case of 10 items, `i%10` will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and then restart at 0, 1, 2, ... again, so it always wraps around.

For the y coordinate, I use `i/10`. Be aware that this is an integer division, so the braces are important. In case of ten items, `i/10` will be 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 and then 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...

That way you even get rid of the `if` statement.

(Note that I introduced some variables to get rid of "magic numbers". You might convert them to constants for optimization. And you should further introduce a name for the two magic numbers 3, which is horizontalMargin and verticalMargin)

Comment: You are quite right that 3 is margin. I chose to make it 3 because that's the default designer margin so it will be consistent.